# Implicit Differentiation True or False?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

If $\dfrac{1}{x+\sin{x}}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1$ and $y(\pi)=0,$ then $y=\cos{x}+x^2-\pi^2+1.\;$ True or False?

I think this is false because I got $y=\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\cos \left(x\right)-\dfrac{\pi ^2}{2}-1$.

Is this right or did I mess up?

Comment: You could find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and verify if by replacing this in the first equation you get an equality.

Comment: Write $\frac{dy}{dx}=x+\sin(x)$ and integrate both sides, remembering the constant of integration.

Comment: I think you are right. You can get back your $y$ by integration and using the initial condition which is exactly what you get.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you get from the equation:
$$\dfrac{1}{x+\sin{x}}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1\Rightarrow dy=(x+\sin x)dx\Rightarrow \\
\int dy=\int (x+\sin x)dx\Rightarrow y=\frac{x^2}{2}-\cos x+C;\\
y(\pi)=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\cos \pi +C=0\Rightarrow C=-\frac{\pi^2}{2}-1;\\
y=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\cos x-\frac{\pi^2}{2}-1.$$
This is what you get from the answer:
$$y(\pi)=\cos \pi +\pi^2-\pi^2+1=0 \quad \checkmark\\
y'=(\cos{x}+x^2-\pi^2+1)'=-\sin x+2x \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{2x-\sin x}\frac{dy}{dx}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. Since $\frac{dy}{dx}=x+\sin(x)$, there must be a number $C$ such that $y=\frac{x^2}{2}-\cos(x)+C$. From $y(\pi)=0$ we get that $C=-\frac{\pi^2}{2}-1$, and so
$$
y=\frac{x^2}{2}-\cos(x)-\frac{\pi^2}{2}-1\neq\cos(x)+x^2-\pi^2+1 \, .
$$